# Core Data migration from UIManagedDocument to normal stack

Tags: ios, core-data, migration, uimanageddocument

I've just started working on an app that uses UIManagedDocument for persistence. As far as I can tell, the only reason UIManagedDocument was used was to take advantage of it automatically setting up a core data stack.

Now, I need to change the data model to implement some new features. The changes to the data model are going to be drastic, and I'm thinking about switching away from UIManagedDocument to a normal core data stack. I've been reading a lot about core data migrations and UIManagedDocument, but to go from UIManagedDocument to a normal CoreData stack, it looks like I'll have to write a class that would migrate the data? I'm just wondering what the best/safest way to do this is.

Answer (score 0):

What migration(s) you need depend only on how the data model changes. Moving from a stack created by `UIManagedDocument` to one that you create should have no significance as far as data migration goes. If there were multiple documents, you'd have to figure out how you wanted to handle that, but if `UIManagedDocument` was used solely to avoid writing boilerplate stack setup code, that's not an issue.

Since you describe the model changes as "drastic", you'll have to look into configuring the migration. You might just need a custom mapping model, or you might need to go for full custom migration code. It really depends on the details of how the model is changing.

Comment: But the migration only helps with moving to a new model. I'll still need to move the data out of UIManagedDocument's stack and into my own, which would require my own custom code anyway. Is that correct? That's why I'm wondering if there's any benefit to using the provided migration tools.

Comment: You should be able to access the UIManagedDocuments database directly as long as you know what its URL is.  Usually its in a subfolder of the UIManagedDocument package, but its a bit more complicated if its using iCloud.  Its not clear why you don't want to use UIManagedDocument, its not going to make your database migration any more difficult (or any easier).  To migrate the database file to another location just use NSPersistentStoreCoordinators migrationPersistentStore...

Comment: BTW the above will only help you make a copy of the existing data store.  To convert the model to your new model you may have to create a new store and then run your custom code to read data from the old store and copy it in to the new store.